# What is best way to compare 2 arrays for new and removed elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have one initial array and then I have added few new elements and removed some existing elements.

Now what is the best way to compare the altered array with original array to determine what are added and what are removed?

Comment: Use `.filter` with a `.indexOf` predicate on the other array.

Comment: What have you tried, can you give an example? Did you have a specific problem with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to see added items, you need to find a difference between existing items and nonexisting in the second array.

Lets call the first array - `A` and second - `B`.

So now removed items would be `difference(A, B)` and inserted items would be `difference(B, A)`

If you're using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) you can simply do it like this:

`var removed = _(A).difference(B);
var added = _(B).difference(A);`

For example you have `A = [1,2,3,4]; B = [3,4,5,6];` so then `removed` will contain `[1, 2]` and `added` will contain `[5, 6]`

**EDIT**
You can of course write your own `difference()` but using **underscore.js** or **lodash** has proven their usability in my practice. Of course you can always use `filter()` or `reduce()`

Comment: Difference logic in combination with filter function worked.

function difference(arrayA, arrayB){
 var diff = arrayA.filter(function(item, i) {
  return arrayB.indexOf(item) === -1;       
 });
 return diff;
}

var A = [1,3,4,5], B = [1,2,4,6];
var a_minus_b = difference(A,B);
var b_minus_a = difference(B,A);
console.log(a_minus_b);//removed 3,5
console.log(b_minus_a);//added 2,6

Comment: Also ExtJS provides Ext.Array.difference(array1, array2) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
OrignalArray = OrignalArray.filter(function(val) {
  return ModifiedArray.indexOf(val) == -1;
});
```

If you want to refer more info then look into

[Filter Option in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

And apply your logic while filtering.